# What is the benefit of using getallheaders() instead of apache_request_headers()?

Tags: php, apache, php-7.3, rector

When using Rector as an aid in upgrading php versions from 7.2 to 7.3, one rule (RenameFunctionRector) changes all instances of `apache_request_headers()` to `getallheaders()`.

After reading the documentation for both functions, it appears that `getallheaders()` is an alias and there's no difference between the two as far as I can see. Can anyone explain the reason why `getallheaders()` exists and if there's any benefit to implementing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`apache_request_headers` was [flagged for possible deprecation in 7.4](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_4). Although that didn't happen, I think it was [added to Rector](https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/issues/893) just in case it did happen eventually.

As for why it was flagged for deprecation, [this thread talks](https://externals.io/message/106012#106175) about it, but basically that function's name implies it is Apache-specific, however there are other SAPIs besides that.